# How to compare a list indice (grid), with piece elements?

Tags: list, python-3.6, python-3.7, indices

```
grid = []
piece = ( (0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3) )

for f in range(18):
    grilla_vacia.append([])
    for c in range(9):
        if [f][c] in piece:
            grilla_vacia[f].append(1)
        grilla_vacia[f].append(0)
```

How can I do, to add '1' in the grid, on the positions that are 'busy' by the piece? The commented line throw up this error: 'list index out of range'

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Should be a grid of 18 rows and 9 columns, when the coordinates of the piece matchs the coordinates of the row/column, it shows '1', everywhere else, shows '0'

For example in the piece of the code(it's an I from tetris):
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
....

Comment: Ok Francisco...Check out my solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help you:

```
import numpy as np

piece = ( (0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3) )
grid = np.zeros((9,18),dtype=int).tolist()

for p in piece:
    grid[p[1]][p[0]] = 1

print(grid)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Here is a solution without `numpy`:

```
piece = ( (0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3) )

grid = [0 for x in range(9*18)]
grid = [grid[i:i+9] for i in range(0, len(grid), 9)]

for p in piece:
    grid[p[1]][p[0]] = 1

print(grid)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: That looks very nice, thanks, and there is any way to do it withouth numpy? just with cycles

Comment: Why? Are you restricted from using `numpy`?

Comment: @FranciscoDuca Check out my latest edit. If my answer has helped you, pls make sure that u upvote my answer and accept it as the best answer by clicking on the green tick mark near my answer. Thank you!

Comment: Done, sorry first time using this platform. Thank you!

Comment: I think your output has 18 columns instead of 9, but it will work fine

Comment: Oh...You want 18 rows and 9 columns? Check out my latest edit. I have changed it to 9.